# Creating a dictionary through SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can create a dictionary through two columns in a database using SQLAlchemy and Python without using a for loop, since this would result in 1000+ queries.  A way to do this in 1 query would be awesome, but I'm stumped.

For example given a table:

**Item**__________**Brand**

Cereal________FrostedFlakes

Phone________Samsung

Cereal________Cheerios

Phone________Apple

Water________Dasani

It will result in a dictionary: {'Cereal': ['FrostedFlakes', 'Cheerios'], 'Phone': ['Samsung', 'Apple'], 'Water': ['Dasani']}
and append each same named item with its brand(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a groupby operation if your table is in a dataframe.

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('db connection string')
df = pd.read_sql_table('Table',engine)
df.groupby('Item')['Brand'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single database query but you will have to iterate through all the returned rows to group the brands by item.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Items(Base):
    item = Column(String)
    brand = Column(String)

results = defaultdict(list)
for item, brand in session.query(Items.item, Items.brand).all():
    results[item] += [brand]
```